# How to disable Safari text corrections?

Tags: safari, autocorrect

How to disable text corrections in Safari?

While typing Safari can change the text. How to prevent Safari from this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the Menu Bar at the top of the screen choose **Edit**
2. Select **Spelling and Grammar**
3. Uncheck **Correct Spelling Automatically**

Comment: Unfortunately this only lasts as long as the current session. What if you *never* want this feature?

Comment: Uncheck **Correct Spelling Automatically** menu item. It works permanently, not just for a session.

Comment: I tried that, it came back on when I restarted Safari. BigSur 11.6.8, Safari 15.6.

Comment: Try this: On your Mac, choose Apple menu  > System Preferences, click Keyboard, then click Text > Uncheck "Correct Spelling Automatically". You can find more info here: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp2299/11.0/mac/11.0